# QueryDSL bindings for Spring Data JPA with Neo4j

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

we have the functionality for the Spring Data JPA where we are using the querydsl like this

Here is my Entity:

```
@Entity
@RestResource(path = "car", rel = "car")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)   
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class CarEntity extends VehicleEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long inventoryId;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String make;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String model;

    @Column(length = 500)
    private String vin;

    @Column(length = 500)
    private String type;
}
```

Here is my repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "car")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public interface CarEntityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<CarEntity, Long>,
        QueryDslPredicateExecutor<CarEntity>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QCarEntity> {

    @Override
    default public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QCarEntity root) {
       bindings.bind(String.class).first(
                (StringPath path, String value) -> path.likeIgnoreCase(value));
    }}
```

with the above code i am able to achieve the QueryDSL functionality and query the entity based on any fields in the entity.

Now as we are migrating to the Neo4j from sql server here is my entity for the same

```
@NodeEntity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CarEntity extends VehicleEntity {
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long inventoryId;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String make;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String model;

    @Column(length = 500)
    private String vin;

    @Column(length = 500)
    private String type;
}
```

Here is my repository for the same

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
public interface CarRepository extends 
           Neo4jRepository<CarEntity,Long> {}
```

these are some of versions and properties for my Neo4j app

```
springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
dependencies {

    // Neo4j
    compile ('org.neo4j:neo4j:3.4.9')
    compile ('org.neo4j.driver:neo4j-java-driver:1.7.2')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j')
    compile ('org.hibernate.ogm:hibernate-ogm-neo4j:5.4.1.Final')

    // Spring
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')

    //lombok
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.2')

    // Testing
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.neo4j:neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver:3.1.11')
    testCompile('org.neo4j.test:neo4j-harness:3.4.9')

    // HTTP (Requesting token for integration tests)
    testCompile('junit:junit')
    testCompile("com.jayway.restassured:rest-assured:$restAssuredVersion")
    testCompile "org.springframework:spring-test:$springVersion"
    testCompile("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion")
    testCompile("com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:$retrofitVersion")

}
```

after building my app which is using Neo4J it's not generating QCarEntity class, and not able to bind to achieve likeIgnoranceCase or etc features provided by QueryDSL.

Can anyone know if there is any library i can use to bind the Neo4j entities and how to generate the QCarEntity class while doing the build

I have tried like this

```
public interface CarEntityRepository extends Neo4jRepository<CarEntity,Long>, PagingAndSortingRepository<CarEntity, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<CarEntity>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QCarEntity> {

@Override
default public void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QCarEntity root) {
    bindings.bind(String.class).first(
            (StringPath path, String value) -> path.likeIgnoreCase(value));
} 
}
```

It's failing to build and not able to generate QCarEntity class, if at all generates QCarEntity, is there a way to achieve this functionality ? Is there any class or library which is similar in Neo4j

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data Neo4j **does not** support QueryDSL.

Supported repository functionality can be checked in the table [on this page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/5.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#neo4j-repo-intro).

You will notice that QueryDslPredicateExecutor is not supported.

And [according to Gerrit Meier](https://community.neo4j.com/t/spring-data-neo4j-querydslpredicateexecutor-general-question/5849), there are no plans to implement it in the near future.